# Grouping data based on object properties

Tags: javascript

I came across this scenario of implementing grouping on the basis of JavaScript object properties.

Here's the input:

```
[
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 7,
    'D': 67
  },
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 7,
    'D': 69
  }
]
```

Here's the output I am expecting:

```
{
  name: 1,
  children: [
    {
      name: 5,
      children: [
        {
          name: 7,
          children: [
            {
              name: 67
            },
            {
              name: 69
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The reason why I am looking for the above output is that I am planning to use it in one of the charts which expects data this way.

Another example input:

```
[
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 4,
    'D': 67
  },
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 7,
    'D': 69
  }
]
```

Expected output:

```
{
  name: 1,
  children: [
    {
      name: 5,
      children: [
        {
          name: 4,
          children: [
            {
              name: 67
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          name: 7,
          children: [
            {
              name: 69
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

The first property that is A will always remain the same, rest of the properties can differ and based on which output can also change.

I am trying to pass in the input data and the keys based on which I want to group this data on - which in my case is [A, B, C, D]

```
  const cstmKey = keys[0];
  const grpdData = {
    name: data[0][cstmKey],
  };

  const grpdValues = data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const customValue = item[cstmKey];
    if (!acc.includes(customValue)) {
      acc.push(customValue);
    }
    return acc;
  }, []);
```

I am planning to map on the  'grpdData'. But not able to come up with anything substantial.

For ordering I was trying to implement it on the basis of a different variable where I can define the order. For eg. - const order = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Comment: What is the significance of the letters? What if instead of "C", there is "Foo"? What determines the order of the keys when determining the depth -- insertion order? lexical order?

Comment: @trincot I have just used it as an example. The idea is that in my scenario, the properties are going to remain the same. So "C" will remain "C" here

Comment: Well, if it is just an example, then you are really saying it might be different, right? What is the varying factor here? What is the element that defines the depth of the group?

Comment: @trincot For ordering I was trying to implement it on the basis of a different variable where I can define the order. For eg. - const order = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']

Comment: Alright. Would be good to add that information to the question.

Comment: @trincot I was trying to use a different variable that will determine the depth as we ll the ordering (as explained above). Please let me know if I am doing something wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would first create a nested object where the keys of your input objects are also keys in the nested object. So for your example, I would first create this:

```
{
    "1": {
        "5": {
            "7": {
                "67": {},
                "69": {}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then convert that object to your target structure with a recursive function.

Like this:

```js
function convert(data, keys) {
    const hierarchy = node => Object.entries(node).map(([name, child]) =>
            Object.keys(child).length ? { name, children: hierarchy(child) } : { name }
        );

    const root = {};
    for (const obj of data) {
        let node = root;
        for (const key of keys) node = (node[obj[key]] ??= {});
    }
    return hierarchy(root)[0];
}

// Example run
const data = [{'A': 1,'B': 5,'C': 7,'D': 67},{'A': 1,'B': 5,'C': 7,'D': 69}];
const result = convert(data, ["A", "B", "C", "D"]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

by analyzing the scenario i think you want to destructure array ob object like for each object entry there is another object nested.
Try this, it might help you.

```js
function createNestedObject(arr) {
    const result = {};
  
    for (const obj of arr) {
      let currentNode = result;
  
      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
        if (!currentNode.children) {
          currentNode.children = [];
        }
  
        let nextNode = currentNode.children.find(node => node.name === value);
  
        if (!nextNode) {
          nextNode = { name: value };
          currentNode.children.push(nextNode);
        }
  
        currentNode = nextNode;
      }
    }
  
    return result.children[0];
  }
  
  const inputArray = [
    {
      'A': 1,
      'B': 5,
      'C': 7,
      'D': 67
    },
    {
      'A': 1,
      'B': 5,
      'C': 7,
      'D': 69
    }
  ];
  
  const nestedObject = createNestedObject(inputArray);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(nestedObject, null, 2));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

As you have your input and hierarchy declared, you can use the following algorithm to create your tree result item by item. I would note that you final result needs to be an array as well (not an object) and the leaf items have a `children` field as well, but it will be empty. This falls from the consistency of the tree and its nodes.

The code below solves the problem and I tried to walk through what each line(s) is doing.

```js
const input = [
    { 'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 7, 'D': 67 },
    { 'A': 1, 'B': 5, 'C': 7, 'D': 69 }
];
const hierarchy = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'];

function getTree(input, hierarchy) {
    // declare tree
    const tree = [];
    // start cursor at tree root
    let cursor = tree;
    // loop through items of the input
    for (const branch of input) {
        // loop through each level of the hierarchy order
        for (const level of hierarchy) {
            // if node found, move on, if not, add it
            let node = cursor.find(({ name }) => (name === branch[level]));
            if (!node) {
                node = { name: branch[level], children: [] };
                cursor.push(node);
            }
            // move cursor forward
            cursor = node.children;
        }
        // hierarchy ended, reset cursor to tree root
        cursor = tree;
    }
    return tree;
}

console.log(getTree(input, hierarchy));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The only difference is that the names will be strings instead of numbers.

This works by making two passes:

1. Compose a hierarchy of objects, where the keys are the "names"
2. Transform that hierarchy into the desired structure with name/children elements

```js
function compute(inputs, keys){
  
  // first pass: build the hierarchy
  
  function next(node, input, idx){
    const key = keys[idx]
    const name = input[key]
    const child = node[name] = node[name] || {}
    if(idx < keys.length - 1){
      next(child, input, idx + 1)
    }
    return node
  }
  
    const result = inputs.reduce((acc, input) => next(acc, input, 0), {})
  
  // second pass: convert to the desired structure (name/children)
  
  function transform(node){
    return Object.keys(node).map(name => {
        const ret = {name}
      const children = transform(node[name])
      if(children.length){
        ret.children = children
      }
      return ret
    })
  }
  return transform(result)
}

const ids = ['A','B','C','D']
const inputs = [
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 7,
    'D': 67
  },
  {
    'A': 1,
    'B': 5,
    'C': 7,
    'D': 69
  }
]

const result = compute(inputs, ids)

document.write("<pre>" + JSON.stringify(result,null,4) + "</pre>")
```